# Deploying Crystal Reports with default parameters

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-server

i have a report with parameters that have been assigned default values, it works fine while previewing the report but as soon as I publish it to the server the default values dont show up. Can some one help me figure out the best practice in publishing that maintains default value

Thanks

Abey

Comment: If you have access to the Reports Server, you can access the report and set the defaults.

Comment: You mean accessing the reports and setting the defaults from the server?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: up voted because your answer wasn't accepted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to Crystal Reports Server, you set the defaults there.